# Jquery - remove radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons with text label. I try to remove the radio button that does not have value then the radio button was remove successfully, but the problem is its text label, I also want to remove them but i can not. Can anyone show me how to do that? Thank you so much for reading my question!

Comment: provide some code please

Comment: can you show your HTML?

Comment: better would be to wrap radio button and label in a span/div and remove the entire span/div

Comment: or else you can use `closest()` method

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7q4yy48o/

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the label when you remove the button with the name hidden for example. Then in the .css set the `.hidden { display: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

you have two options

1. you can add same class name for both radio and text field and hide the class
   eg:

`<input type="radio" class="myclass" >
<label class="myclass">abc</label>
$(".myclass").hide();`

2.also you can add input feild and lable to Div,hide div
eg:-

`<div id="mydiv">
  <input type="radio" ><label >abc</label>
 </div>
 $("#mydiv").hide();`

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you, use `element.each` to find all the radios without value and remove them ...

Here in this code, only first radio will be displayed because it has value and the second one is removed and the label for second is also removed...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[type="radio"]:not([value])').each(function() {
        var idVal = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).remove();
        $("label[for='"+idVal+"']").remove();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="submit" id="submit" action="#" method="post">
 
  <label for="one">First Item</label>
  <input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="1" />

  <label for="two">Second Item</label>
  <input type="radio" id="two" name="first_item"  />            
</form>
```